# indefinite integrals of absolute values

Tags: calculus, indefinite-integrals

The simplest possible case is confusing to me. Namely:
$$
\int |x| dx = \cases { \int x dx = x^2/2 + C & $x \ge 0$ \\ -\int x dx = -x^2/2 + C & $x < 0$ }
$$

However, since $|x|$ is non-negative, by comparison theorem it's integral should also be non-negative, even for negative $x$, but the integral is negative for any non-empty negative interval. Do you know what I am missing?

Thanks!

Comment: Once you evaluate it, it will be positive.

Comment: How come, when $-x^2$ is negative?

Comment: $\int_{-1}^0 -x \ dx = 0 - \frac{-1}{2}= + \frac{1}{2}$.

Comment: Think about $f(x)=\cos x$. This is non-negative over the interval $[-\pi/2,0]$ yet its integral is $\sin(x) + C$ which is "negative"* over the same interval. Does that bother you?  *It shouldn't, since it makes no sense to call it "negative":  with $C=10000$ it is actually not negative.

Comment: The point:  $\sin x$ is indeed negative, but the general antiderivative $\sin (x) + C$ is not.  In fact, it makes no sense to talk about it being "negative."

Comment: (i) The fact $|x|$ is non-negative means the antiderivative is _increasing_, not _positive_. (ii) FWIW, if $n \geq 0$ then $\int |x|x^{n-1}\, dx = \frac{1}{n+1}|x|x^{n} + C$.

Comment: Thank you, all! It seems like all of you covered the second part of the original question, so I kept that, and I split now the first part of the question into a new one https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4414370/case-analysis-of-indefinite-integrals. I would prefer if any of you can now write the complete answer, so I can close this question.

Comment: I deleted because I thought I was making the wrong point.  Maybe I'll revisit.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, integrals should be treated with care around points of discontinuity.  For this reason, integrals should be treated independently on separate intervals where the integrand is continuous.  However, in practice, this rarely matters.  The Mean Value Theorem guarantees that any two antiderivatives of $f(x)$ will differ only by a constant **across an interval**.  So, if you have to "jump" over a discontinuity this will cause you to work over two separate intervals.  The good example is that the integral of $\frac{1}{x^2}$ should really look like
$$
\int \frac{1}{x^2} \ dx = \begin{cases} -\frac{1}{x}+C_1, & x > 0 \\ -\frac{1}{x}+C_2, & x < 0.\end{cases}
$$
However, we wouldn't integrate over an interval that crosses over $0$ anyway, so in practice you only need one of these cases, but they both have the exact same form.  Hence, we get lazy about the distinction, but you are right, the most general form has an independent constant for each interval of continuity.

For the second question, the **definite** integral of a non-negative continuous function will, in fact, be non-negative.  Key word:  **definite** integral.

You are confounding the definite integral with the general antiderivative.  In fact, you cannot say that a general antiderivative is "negative" (or positive, or non-negative) because it is not one function but an infinite class of functions "parameterized" by your choice of $C$.  So, for some $C$ it could be negative, for others not, and for many choices, both.  But it doesn't really matter, since you should really be asking about what the definite integral does.

Comment: Yes, thank you, that second part of the question is now clear. But could you also answer the first part of the question, so I can consider it answered (and close it)?

Comment: Sure, give me a sec.