# How to integrate $\int \sqrt{\cos^{2}(x)}dx$?

Tags: calculus, integration, indefinite-integrals, trigonometric-integrals

How to integrate $$\int \sqrt{\cos^{2}(x)}dx$$ ? I know that $\sqrt{\cos^{2}(x)}=|\cos(x)|$. Therefore $|\cos(x)|=\cos(x)${when $\cos(x)>0$} , $|\cos(x)|=-\cos(x)${when $\cos(x)<0$} , $|\cos(x)|=0${when $\cos(x)=0$}. Now when $|\cos(x)|=\cos(x)$, then the result of the above integral will be $$\int \cos(x)dx=\sin(x)+C$$. When $|\cos(x)|=-\cos(x)$, then the result of the above integral will be $$\int -\cos(x)dx=-\sin(x)+C_1$$. And finally when $|\cos(x)|=0$, then the result of the above integral will be $0$. Therefore, we can clearly see here that $3$ different results are occuring. So, finally I thought of writing $|\cos(x)|=\cos(x)sgn(\cos(x))$. Therefore we can write the above integral as $$\int \sqrt{\cos^{2}(x)}dx$$= $$\int |\cos(x)|dx$$= $$\int \cos(x)sgn(\cos(x))dx$$. Now I am facing problem to integrate $$\int \cos(x)sgn(\cos(x))dx$$. So, please help me out with this integral.

Comment: Wolfram functions already had the answer [here](https://functions.wolfram.com/EllipticIntegrals/EllipticE2/03/01/01/0003/)

Comment: Possible explanations [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4413266/indefinite-integrals-of-absolute-values) and [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4414370/case-analysis-of-indefinite-integrals?noredirect=1&lq=1)?

Answer (score 1):

Since

$$\mbox{sgn}\cos x= \frac{\sqrt{\cos^2 x}}{\cos x},$$

You can just write

$$\int \sqrt{\cos^2 x} \; dx = \frac{\sqrt{\cos^2 x}}{\cos x}\sin x +C.$$

Comment: Why you considered $sgn(\cos(x))$ to be a constant?@B.Goddard

Comment: It's not constant and I don't assume it to be a constant.

Comment: How you evaluated $\int cos(x)sgn(cos(x))dx$ ?@B. Goddard

Comment: @SyamaprasadChakrabarti,Evaluate the integral By taking two cases,After that One of Them will be $\sin x$ for $\cos x>0$,and Other will be $-\sin x$ for $\cos x \leq0$,Which means Integral depends on sign of $\cos x$,hence can be written as $(sgn(\cos x))\sin x$ which then Includes both cases